# How to highlight some specific rows on the print layout of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to highlight specific rows while printing data from the jquery data table. I added a class to those rows by `createdRow` and added some CSS style to that class. Now I want to keep that styling on those rows while printing.
The code I've used to add class

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
    var date = new Date(data.dateOfReg);
    var days = datediff(date, new Date());

    if (days >= 30 && parseInt(data.received) < 2000 && parseInt(data.payment) >= 2000) {
       $(row).addClass('d-flag');
    }    
}
```

[image]

In the image, you can see some rows have a background color. I just want to keep that while printing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find a solution for this by looping through on `customize` callback function something like this -

```
customize: function (win) {
    $(win.document.body).find('table tbody tr').each(function (index) {
        var dateOfReg = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text();
        var date = new Date(dateOfReg.split('-')[2], dateOfReg.split('-')[1], dateOfReg.split('-')[0]);

        var payment = $(this).find('td:eq(5)').text();
        var received = $(this).find('td:eq(6)').text();
        
        var days = datediff(date, new Date());

        if (days >= 30 && parseInt(received) < 2000 && parseInt(payment) >= 2000) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#e4e4e4');
        }
    });
});
```